# Python dataframe first week with complete 7 days data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have data frame containing years of data. I want to plot the first week's data that has all seven days.

My code:

```
# Extract first week data from the dataframe
first_week_index=df1.loc[(df1.index.isocalendar().week==1)].index
DatetimeIndex(['2005-01-03 00:00:00', '2005-01-03 01:00:00',
               '2005-01-03 02:00:00', '2005-01-03 03:00:00',
               '2005-01-03 04:00:00', '2005-01-03 05:00:00',
               '2005-01-03 06:00:00', '2005-01-03 07:00:00',
               '2005-01-03 08:00:00', '2005-01-03 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2018-01-07 14:00:00', '2018-01-07 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 16:00:00', '2018-01-07 17:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 18:00:00', '2018-01-07 19:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 20:00:00', '2018-01-07 21:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 22:00:00', '2018-01-07 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datetime', length=2352, freq=None)
# As you can see in the above result, I cannot plot the first year (2005) first week data as it starts with 3rd day. 
# It does not have the first two days of the first week. Hence, I should search in this index, 
# which year's first week has all seven days data

# Only the first week with complete seven days of data
first_week_dates = first_week_index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique()
first_week_dates = pd.to_datetime(first_week_dates,format='%Y-%m-%d')
year_with_firstWeek_7days = first_week_dates.year.value_counts()
```

Present output:

```
print(year_with_firstWeek_7days)

2007    7
2018    7
2006    6
2008    6
2012    6
2013    6
2017    6
2005    5
2011    5
2014    5
2009    4
2010    4
2015    4
2016    4
Name: Datetime, dtype: int64
```

Now I know that only year 2007 and 2018s first week have complete seven days of data. I will plot it. This is fine. But my approach seems long and lengthy. Can you suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the first day number of each year using the following code

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2005-01-01 00:00:00', end='2019-
01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'), columns=['dateTime'])

In [2]: d = {year: df.loc[df.dateTime == f'{year}-01-01 00:00:00'].iloc[0][0].
    dayofweek for year in df.dateTime.dt.year.unique()}
```

The output is like this:

```
{2005: 5, 2006: 6, 2007: 0, 2008: 1, 2009: 3, 2010: 4, 2011: 5, 2012: 6,
 2013: 1, 2014: 2, 2015: 3, 2016: 4, 2017: 6, 2018: 0, 2019: 1}
```

In years like 2007 when the start day is 0, the first week has 7 days. In the following, I compare the timing performance of these two approaches.

```
In [3]: def func_1():
   ...:     first_week_dates = df.dateTime.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique()
   ...:     first_week_dates = pd.to_datetime(first_week_dates,format='%Y-%m-%d')
   ...:     year_with_firstWeek_7days = first_week_dates.year.value_counts()

In [10]: def func_2():
   ...:     d = {year: df.loc[df.dateTime == f'{year}-01-01 00:00:00'].iloc[0][0].dayofweek for year in df.dateTime.dt.year.unique()}

In [27]: %timeit func_1()
32.5 ms ± 540 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit func_2()
5.92 ms ± 23.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: The assumption here with start day 0 means all seven days of data are present. In reality, some days may also be missing with start day 0.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution and that is:

```
# consider days only with the dayofyear >0 and < 8. This ensures January 1st 
# will be treated as day1, 7th will be as day 7. 
first_week_index=df1.loc[(df1.index.dayofyear>0)&(df1.index.dayofyear<8)].index
# Only first week that definitely has first seven days data
first_week_dates = first_week_index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique()
first_week_dates = pd.to_datetime(first_week_dates,format='%Y-%m-%d')
year_first_week_days = first_week_dates.year.value_counts()
year_with_firstWeek_7days = year_first_week_days[year_first_week_days.eq(7)].index
```