# Python Dataframe index isocaldenar() code giving different answers in a span of 2 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I am in a perfect state of confusion and dilemma. I don't know what is going on. I had raised a question couple of days ago with some sample data and code. I already had a working solution but was looking for short one. This is fine.

I am running the code again today, but this time, I am getting a different answer. I am surprised and puzzled.

The original posted question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717066/python-dataframe-first-week-with-complete-7-days-data/75742727#75742727). My dataset has 2005-2018 data. This is about finding the years with all seven data days in the first week. I assumed 2005-01-01 to 07 will be Week 1, and so on, similarly for the remaining years.
This was the solution I got, and this was correct for me.

But the same code I am running today gives me a different answer.

```
year_first_week_days=
2008    9
2007    8
2012    8
2013    8
2014    8
2005    7
2006    7
2010    7
2011    7
2016    7
2017    7
2018    7
2009    4
2015    4
Name: Datetime, dtype: int64

first_week_dates=
DatetimeIndex(['2005-01-03', '2005-01-04', '2005-01-05', '2005-01-06',
               '2005-01-07', '2005-01-08', '2005-01-09', '2006-01-02',
               '2006-01-03', '2006-01-04', '2006-01-05', '2006-01-06',
               '2006-01-07', '2006-01-08', '2007-01-01', '2007-01-02',
               '2007-01-03', '2007-01-04', '2007-01-05', '2007-01-06',
               '2007-01-07', '2007-12-31', '2008-01-01', '2008-01-02',
               '2008-01-03', '2008-01-04', '2008-01-05', '2008-01-06',
               '2008-12-29', '2008-12-30', '2008-12-31', '2009-01-01',
               '2009-01-02', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04', '2010-01-04',
               '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-08',
               '2010-01-09', '2010-01-10', '2011-01-03', '2011-01-04',
               '2011-01-05', '2011-01-06', '2011-01-07', '2011-01-08',
               '2011-01-09', '2012-01-02', '2012-01-03', '2012-01-04',
               '2012-01-05', '2012-01-06', '2012-01-07', '2012-01-08',
               '2012-12-31', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03',
               '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06', '2013-12-30',
               '2013-12-31', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03',
               '2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-12-29', '2014-12-30',
               '2014-12-31', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03',
               '2015-01-04', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06',
               '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-09', '2016-01-10',
               '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05',
               '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-08', '2018-01-01',
               '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05',
               '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datetime', freq=None)
```

The problem I found is, for instance, in year 2008, where it is showing nine days for week 1 `('2008-01-01', '2008-01-02','2008-01-03', '2008-01-04', '2008-01-05', '2008-01-06','2008-12-29', '2008-12-30', '2008-12-31')`, it considered last three days `('2008-12-29', '2008-12-30', '2008-12-31')` of the year as week 1. This is the case for the remaining years as well. Why is it doing this? Any help?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar), "The ISO year consists of 52 or 53 full weeks, and where a week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. The first week of an ISO year is the first (Gregorian) calendar week of a year containing a Thursday. This is called week number 1, and the ISO year of that Thursday is the same as its Gregorian year. For example, 2004 begins on a Thursday, so the first week of ISO year 2004 begins on Monday, 29 Dec 2003 and ends on Sunday, 4 Jan 2004:"

Comment: If you're picking dates where `dt.isocalendar().week==1`, you probably want to groupby `dt.isocalendar().year` instead of `dt.year`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to define "week 1" as 1st-7th Jan instead of the ISO definition, then your filter would be `dt.dayofyear <= 7` rather than `dt.isocalendar().week==1`. In that case you can group by `dt.year` when doing your `value_counts()`.

Comment: The basic problem is in fact pretty similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717408/python-dataframe-isocalendar-boolean-condition-not-producing-desired-result-wh - if you mix ISO week with Gregorian year, you'll find some odd behaviour like the "9 days in week 1 of 2008" that you're showing here.